# Is there a JSON schema for Google Cloud logging types?

Tags: google-cloud-logging

The [discovery document](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/reference/v2/rest) for the Google Cloud logging API does not include JSON schema for the logging types [AuditData](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/reference/audit/bigquery/rest/Shared.Types/AuditData) and [AuditLog](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/reference/audit/bigquery/rest/Shared.Types/AuditLog), among others, and I haven't been able to find schemas anywhere else. Do they exist?

I'm writing client libraries for various Google Cloud APIs, using the discovery documents to generate code, but when it comes to logging I am hindered by the lack of JSON schemas.

Comment: As per this [cloud logging doc](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/reference/v2/rest/v2/LogEntry) , you can get the JSON schema for LogEntry, LogSeverity, LogSplit,LogEntryOperation, HttpRequest and JSON can be created only for the structured data. Refer to this [Structured Logging](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/structured-logging)  by this You can write structured logs to Logging in several ways. 

The other way is you can also create and register a schema by following this [official documentation](https://developers.google.com/cloud-search/docs/guides/schema-guide) .

Comment: Yes, the [discover document for the cloud logging API](https://logging.googleapis.com/$discovery/rest?version=v2) contains a schema for LogEntry. But then LogEntry has a field protoPayload that contains the really useful stuff (at least for BigQuery logging), which contains structured data in the format specified by the @type field, for example [AuditLog](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/reference/audit/bigquery/rest/Shared.Types/AuditLog). The latter schema is not provided in any discovery document.

Comment: Unfortunately as per the cloud documentation of logEntry protoPayload, only given protocol buffer types are supported; user-defined types are not supported. Google has not provided later schemas. But as per this [Special fields in structured payloads](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/agent/logging/configuration#special-fields), `When the Logging agent receives a structured log record, it moves any key that matches the following table into the corresponding field in the LogEntry object. Otherwise, the key becomes part of the LogEntry.jsonPayload field`.

Comment: As there are no later schemas and  this is a valid and most useful request to achieve this, you can fill a `Feature Request` in [GCP IssueTracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers) to create this possibility.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is there are no such schemas. Created https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/302436277 to request them.

Answer (score 0):

I have provided my comments as an answer :

- As per the [Cloud documentation](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/reference/v2/rest/v2/LogEntry) of logEntry protoPayload,

> only the following protocol buffer types are supported; user-defined
> types are not supported:
>
> [`type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.audit.AuditLog`](http://type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.audit.AuditLog)
> [`type.googleapis.com/google.appengine.logging.v1.RequestLog`](http://type.googleapis.com/google.appengine.logging.v1.RequestLog)

- `Google has not provided later schemas`. As there are no later schemas and this is a valid and most useful request to achieve this, you can fill a Feature Request in [GCP IssueTracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers) to create this possibility.